# In XAML bind Text to x index of static collection with x being supplied by the y index of another collection?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding

I have a static collection of strings and would like to display one of these strings from a certain index. That index is supplied at run time, and is an integer value in the second index in another collection.

I can bind to the static collection, but how do I bind the path to the value in the other 
collection?
That is, **what do I use as a value to the Path argument in the TextBlock binding?**

The code here is just for experimenting and is not part of the working code. It is Visual Studio Designer friendly, and if I get the binding right, it will show Wednesday in the designer without running:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingCollectionIndex.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingCollectionIndex"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AnotherClass
        x:Key="Foo" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyStaticCollections.Days},
        Path=[**Wrong ... Foo.CollectionOfIntegers[2]**]}" />
</Grid>
```

The static class:

```
           using System.Collections.Generic;

            namespace BindingCollectionIndex
        {
            static class MyStaticCollections
            {
                public static List<string> Days =new List<string> { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
            }
        }
```

The class that supplies the index value:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BindingCollectionIndex
{
    class AnotherClass
    {
        private ObservableCollection<int> collectionOfIntegers = new ObservableCollection<int>
        {
            1,2,3,4,5
        };
        public ObservableCollection<int> CollectionOfIntegers
        {
            get
            {
                return collectionOfIntegers;
            }

        }
    }
```

}

There is nothing added to the xaml's code behind.

Thanks for reading.
David

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a Dictionary?

```
class DaysViewModel
{
    public IDictionary<int,string> Days { get; set; }

    public DaysViewModel()
    {
        Days = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                {1,"Monday"},
                {2,"Tuesday"},
                {3,"Wednesday"},
                {4,"Thursday"},
                {5,"Friday"}
            };

    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DaysViewModel x:Key="Week" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Week},Path=Days[2]}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I devised the example to help show the problem in a simple fashion, what I am trying to do really is more complex. I could have got 'Wednesday' to display just by putting '2' in the Path argument of my OP but I would like an answer on the binding question. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, then I did not really understand where you are heading. Maybe discribe your application a little more specific. Are you going to select the list from some sort of list or where does it come from?